# S3Export function --I need table to be exported as gzip file

Tags: vertica

I want to export data from Vertica table on to S3, i am able to do it using vertica's S3Export Function.
But i want exported data in compressed form eg. gzip.

Pelase help, let me know how to do it using S3Export function.

Thanks.

Comment: What about writing to a named pipe with gip reading from the other side of the pipe?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot gzip while using the S3Export fnct in Vertica.

You can create single objects vbr backups and tar.gz them and copy to S3, i find this to be much faster and more space efficient than the S3Export.

example :

```
#!/bin/bash

Initiate backup location
/opt/vertica/bin/vbr.py -t init -c /home/dbadmin/scripts/dba/vbr/vbr_conf/obj-bak.ini

Run Backup
/opt/vertica/bin/vbr.py -t backup -c /home/dbadmin/scripts/dba/vbr/vbr_conf/obj-bak.ini

#Move into the backup directory
cd /backup_area/

export date=`date +"%Y%m%d"`
tar czf bkp_daily_$date.tar.gz * --remove-files

Copy the gz file to AWS S3
aws s3 mv /backup_area/bkp_daily_$date.tar.gz s3://vertica-object-backup/
```